# How to make handler request that gets back json

Tags: c#, json, handler

I have a handler that returns json

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    HttpResponse response = context.Response;
    response.ContentType = "application/json";

    string controlType = context.Request.QueryString["controlType"];
    JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    CmsManager cmsManager = new CmsManager();
    IDictionary<string, Guid> sitefinityPageDictionary = SitefinityUtilities.sitefinityPageDictionary;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(controlType)) {
        response.Write("0");
    }
    else {
        var pagesWithControl = from page in sitefinityPageDictionary
                               from control in cmsManager.GetPage(page.Value).Controls
                               where control.TypeName == controlType
                               select page;
        response.Write(jsonSerializer.Serialize(pagesWithControl));
    }
}
```

In a seperate project I would like to make a request to the handler to consume the json object returned.

1. Would `HttpRequest` be the appropriate object to use to make a request to the handler?
2. Could someone provide a simple example of how to request and consume the json object from another c# class (not javascript)?

Comment: Take into account cross domain restictions in order to consume this from a different project. You'd need to use jsonp if you plan to access this from javascript in a different domain.

Comment: made changes to op. I need to know how to request and consume from c# side, not javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have a way to consume a json object from c#

```
IList<MyClass> myClassList = null;
var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

string json;
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        json = sr.ReadToEnd();
        var javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        myClassList = javaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<List<MyClass>>(json);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would need to be able to parse the json returned. is it possible to have a `var` and then i can loop through the json?

Comment: you could use jsonSerializer.Deserialize but you'll need to create a class to map the json structure

Comment: Im going to try this with `javaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(json)` and see if that works. Your example is solid though. Thank you!